# Swig Template CLI + Browser Usage + Custom filters

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I'm trying to use Swig template for Nodejs in the browser.

**The requirement:**

I need to use custom filters in my precompiled templates with Swig CLI.

**The issue:**

The result of my compilation doesn't have the custom filters functions and I get an error (Step 5 below).

**The steps I've made**

1- Compile the template

Template:

```
<span>{{ item.sampleProperty|customFilterTwo }}</span>
```

Filters file [filters.js]:

```
module.exports = {
    customFilterTwo: function(sampleProperty) {
        return sampleProperty + " rocks!";
    }
}
```

Command swig CLI:

```
swig compile ./views/macros/item.html > ./views/templates/item.js --filters=./views/filters/filters.js
```

2- Result of compilation

```
var tpl = function (_swig,_ctx,_filters,_utils,_fn) {
  var _ext = _swig.extensions,
    _output = "";
_output += "<span>";
_output += _filters["e"](_filters["customFilterTwo"]((((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? _ctx.item.sampleProperty : "") : ((typeof item !== "undefined" && item !== null && item.sampleProperty !== undefined && item.sampleProperty !== null) ? item.sampleProperty : "")) !== null ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? _ctx.item.sampleProperty : "") : ((typeof item !== "undefined" && item !== null && item.sampleProperty !== undefined && item.sampleProperty !== null) ? item.sampleProperty : "")) : "" )));
_output += "</span>";

  return _output;

};
```

3- Load Swig library and the js of the compiled template in the browser

4- Use the compiled js through the generated function tpl()

```
var html = swig.run(tpl, { 'item': item });
```

5- Get the error when running

```
TypeError: _filters.customFilterTwo is not a function
```

I know I need to tell Swig about the filters, buy I want a fully independent compiled template. I don't want to tell again Swig about these filters.

**My Solution:**

I've been researching about how to do that and I have made some modifications in Swig library to approach this.

In bin/swig.js replace the line 129 with:

```
// Compile any custom filters
var customFilters = "";
    if (argv.filters) {
      utils.each(require(path.resolve(argv.filters)), function (filter, name) {
        customFilters += "_filters['" + name + "'] = " + filter + ";\n";
      });
    }

    var r = swig.precompile(str, { filename: file, locals: ctx, customFilters: customFilters }).tpl.toString().replace('anonymous', '');
```

In lib/swig.js in line 486 add:

```
options.customFilters + '\n' +
```

And the result of the compiled js now have the provided filters:

```
var tpl = function (_swig,_ctx,_filters,_utils,_fn) {
    var _ext = _swig.extensions,
    _output = "";
    _filters["customFilterTwo"] = function(sampleProperty) {
        return sampleProperty + " rocks!";
    };
    _output += "<span>";
    _output += _filters["e"](_filters["customFilterTwo"]((((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? _ctx.item.sampleProperty : "") : ((typeof item !== "undefined" && item !== null && item.sampleProperty !== undefined && item.sampleProperty !== null) ? item.sampleProperty : "")) !== null ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? ((typeof _ctx.item !== "undefined" && _ctx.item !== null && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== undefined && _ctx.item.sampleProperty !== null) ? _ctx.item.sampleProperty : "") : ((typeof item !== "undefined" && item !== null && item.sampleProperty !== undefined && item.sampleProperty !== null) ? item.sampleProperty : "")) : "" )));
    _output += "</span>";

      return _output;

    };
```

And now the script is fully independent and doesn't need add the filters to swig.

---

I wish I have explained well enough. Sorry for my bad English.

I'm killing flies with cannon?? There is another easier way to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The instance of swig in your step 4 needs to also know about your filters.

```
swig.setFilter('customFilterTwo', customFilterTwoMethod);
var html = swig.run(tpl, { 'item', item })
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your great work (Swig).
I know you response is one solution but I don't want this. I need that  my compiled templates have all the required stuff to work by itself providing, of course, the params of the template.

I added the full result of my custom compilation to show you my wished behaviour.

Comment: PD: If I need to provide the filters when compile the js, why I need to provide again when I use the compiled template?

Comment: Providing filters to the compiler merely registers them as being "allowed". The actual functions themselves do not get added, because we assume that you'll want to have more than a single compiled template. If we were to compile each filter and tag function into each template, you'd end up with tons of duplication and bloat.